# Windows 7: copy pasting a .png image causes it to lose transparency?

Tags: windows, image-processing

As the title states.

This is happening to me on Windows with images that have a transparent background.

Is there a way to avoid this on copy - paste?

Comment: What are you pasting the image into?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Or simply, "Mouse-Clicking-Question" ?

Comment: It's an image processing question and it's one of the Stack Overflow tags. I don't see why it wouldn't belong here. You can scroll away if this question doesn't amuse you. I'm curious for the reasons why as Googling didn't help much.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen to me. Is there something different about the folder you're working with?

Comment: What did you copy, an image file or a selected piece of an image? From which application? To what application? How? You need to give more info. Besides, I tend to agree with Abhineet that this is off topic.

Comment: I'm using Windows explorer - selecting a .png image file called "example.png" from the folder "A" (with transparent bg), and copy pasting it (CTRL + C, CTRL + V) into the same folder - and the pasted image file has no transparent background (it's white - transparency is lost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well what I forgot to mention is that after I copy pasted the image, I also resized it using paint expecting paint to preserve transparency.

But it appears Paint doesn't do that.